# Add legend on amchart-php

Tags: php, amcharts

I am using a library to add graphics to my php code only I am not able to insert the captions to the graphic so that the user can hide or show the graph can someone help me?

Class Library https://github.com/fusonic/amcharts-php

**Update**

My code

```
 function getData()
         {
             return array(
                 array(
                     "bolivia" => 989,
                     "argentina" => 7701,
                     "year" => 2000
                 ),
                 array(
                     "bolivia" => 939,
                     "argentina" => 7209,
                     "year" => 2001
                 ),
                 array(
                     "bolivia" => 894,
                     "argentina" => 2712,
                     "year" => 2002
                 ),
                 array(
                     "bolivia" => 955,
                     "argentina" => 3413,
                     "year" => 2003
                 ),
                 array(
                     "bolivia" => 1021,
                     "argentina" => 3997,
                     "year" => 2004
                 ),
                 array(
                     "bolivia" => 1203,
                     "argentina" => 4740,
                     "year" => 2005
                 ),
                 array(
                     "bolivia" => 1356,
                     "argentina" => 5490,
                     "year" => 2006
                 ),
                 array(
                     "bolivia" => 1696,
                     "argentina" => 6630,
                     "year" => 2007
                 ),
                 array(
                     "bolivia" => 1735,
                     "argentina" => 8231,
                     "year" => 2008
                 ),
                 array(
                     "bolivia" => 1935,
                     "argentina" => 7674,
                     "year" => 2009
                 ),
                 array(
                     "bolivia" => 1925,
                     "argentina" => 0133,
                     "year" => 2010
                 ),
             );
         }
         // Require necessary files
         require("AmSerialChart.php");

         // Create a new serial chart
         $chart = new AmSerialChart("myLineChart");

         // Set the path to the amcharts JS library
         $chart->setLibraryPath(_WEB."js/amcharts");

         // Set the X axes to represent the "year" field (optional)
         $chart->setConfig("categoryField", "year");

         // Use a chart cursor (optional)
         $chart->setConfig("chartCursor", array("cursorPointer" => "mouse"));


         // Add the data for the chart to use
         $chart->setData(getData());

         // Add 2 graphs
         $graphConfigBolivia = array(
             "balloonText" => "Bolivia: [[value]] $", 
             "title" => "Asia-Pacific"
         );

         $chart->addGraph("bolivia", $graphConfigBolivia);

         $graphConfigArgentina = array(
             "balloonText" => "Argentina: [[value]] $" ,    
              "title"=> "Asia-Pacific" );

         $chart->addGraph("argentina", $graphConfigArgentina);

         // Get the HTML/JS code
         echo $chart->getCode();
```

Comment: Could you show your code so that we can help you with that

Comment: I already entered the code I use is the example

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the legend property in your config. Add `$chart->setConfig("legend", array());` to your code to get the basic legend enabled.

You'll need to look at the [AmCharts documentation](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/) and [demos](http://www.amcharts.com/demos) to get a better understanding of the JSON configuration and how to map them to the PHP class (or just use JavaScript directly and only use PHP to retrieve your data).